# Create an executable application in Ubuntu with many dependencies?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

We have coded an application with many dependencies. Right now, we can use a makefile to compile source code. What we want to do next is create an executable application (we don't want to release our source code) with the dependencies. Just a compressed file, other users can extract and use it directly. we don't want to provide source code, it seems that debmake can't work.  How to compress the dependencies along with the executable main application?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Proprietary code won't get you far in this community. Some of those dependencies that you need likely *require* you to make your source code available as a condition of their license. We take those licenses seriously, and we obey their terms. Folks who don't have a very poor reputation, and we won't work  with them at all. The first step dealing with the Ubuntu community is to complete a license audit, and to be *completely sure* that you are compliant.

Comment: [AppImage](https://appimage.org/) lets you pack all parts of the application in a single executable file, if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: @danzel Thank you so much, it is